# Lua byte code, size of nil

Tags: lua, byte, bytecode

Im reading [this](http://underpop.free.fr/l/lua/docs/a-no-frills-introduction-to-lua-5.1-vm-instructions.pdf) and developing a virtual machine, Im stuck at reading constants because I don't know howmany bytes to read if the constant is a nil. How many bytes *is* a nil?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No bytes to be read after reading the type because the type says it all in this case. See http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lundump.c.html#LoadConstants.

Comment: So what I read a single byte to get the type and then I read nothing?